# Can I quickly save/load the layout of VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, layout, screen

I often switch between horizontal and vertical screen orientations on my computer. Yet, every time I switch, I need to readjust the layout of VSCode to guarantee the editor is visible and legible. I wonder if there is any way for VSCode to preserve distinct layouts or for it to identify the screen orientation and readjust the layout accordingly.